# WKWebView not loading images from a specific page

Tags: ios, xamarin, wkwebview

I'm opening a specific page inside an app, using WKWebView. Problem is that images contained in that page are not loading.  Instead i get a just frame with a question mark in the middle.

Here's the paste from this page's source from regular browser, responsible of displaying those images.

```
    <div>
            <table>
            <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right" id="foobar">
                            <a rel="productImageGroup"    href="http://media.byggtjeneste.no/media/bilde/340317/xlarge" title="<a
href='http://media.byggtjeneste.no/media/orginalbilde/340317'>Last ned
høyoppløselig bilde</a>"><img alt="Produktbilde" width="240"
height="100"    src="http://media.byggtjeneste.no/media/bilde/340317/small" /></a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe because they are on http

Comment: The images load when url is opened in phone's browser. It's only when I load the same url into WKWebView - the images are missing.

Comment: Did you added in your plist Allow Arbitrary Load

Comment: @karthikeyan -  That did the trick, thank you so much!
I can't neither upvote, nor mark your answer as the solution though...

Comment: @hr4bi0  - I have added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you requested in comments adding as an answer and more about ATS [Doc link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads </key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 9, iOS will only allow your application to communicate with servers that implement best-practice security by default. Values must be set in Info.plist to enable communication with insecure servers.

It is best practice to only enable some domains to bypass ATS, allowing you to use trusted sites while benefitting from the additional security on untrusted domains. The following demonstrates the less secure method of disabling ATS for the app:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads </key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

</key>
```

Comment: Thank you, but karthikeyan get's the accepted answer, as that was the first answer I received.